# Is it okay to have addictions and still call yourself a Buddhist master?

Tags: ethics, vinaya

Some 'Buddhists' believe that it is okay for one to be addicted to smoking and drinking. They give examples of Chogyam Trungpa and the like who were known to indulge in these and other addictions. 
It might seem puritanical, but I don't agree with them, and I believe the Buddha wouldn't either. I think any kind of addiction is connected with cravings and a 'master' cannot be called one until he/she has at least mastered these cravings. I also think that as a Buddhist of any stripe, one follows the Four Noble Truths (and the 8-fold path within it) and if one does, one clearly understands the perils of unregulated cravings. And then there is the issue of creating wrong 'role models' for the followers of the 'master'.
What do people on this forum think about this issue?

Comment: Hello Jagger and welcome to Buddhism.SE. Your question appears to ask for opinions/discussion and as a Best Answer Q & A site, we are not well suited for these type of questions. We do have several questions regarding alcohol consumption among Buddhists already. If none of these answers your question, please try to rephrase your Q in a way that it can be answered objectively. Thanks!

Comment: Similar topics here: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/do-all-buddhists-abstain-from-alcohol, http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2512/is-moderate-drinking-acceptable-in-buddhism/2535#2535,

Comment: I'm putting this on hold; please feel free to edit it and submit for reopening - as Robin says, try to aim for questions looking for a single right answer.

Comment: Apparently Chogyam Trungpa taught "Tibetan Buddhism" so you might ask what role if any such might have within that tradition (i.e. beware of trying to judge it from the perspective of a different school). Also Wikipedia says that he gave up his monastic vows to work as a lay teacher so perhaps the 'vinaya' tag isn't appropriate.

Comment: Sometimes i wonder how people judge others. Putting a q. on hold ! There's one more option with so many another sub options in it, Edit the question.

Comment: @jitin People have tried to discuss the various options on meta: [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1508/254) and [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1524/254) and in the comments to [this question](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1477/254). Putting the Q on hold isn't judging others, I hope: it's giving the OP a chance to rephrase their own question before people try to answer it. If you want to discuss (add to or influence) the policy, please add to the discussions on meta, and/or start a new topic on meta to discuss this specific question.

Comment: I really think there is a good questions in here around seemingly unethical practices of teachers such as Chogyam Trungpa. I think if it was reformulated to ask about his actions and how this fit in with his lineage then it would be very interesting. It's a question that I've had in mind to ask to be honest

Comment: @jitin putting the question on hold prevents answers to a problematic question. As it stands, my assumption is that this question would solicit opinions, not expert answers. The idea is to prevent answers until the question can be reworded to fit the format of this site. If you think the question was closed in error, please vote to reopen the question. There certainly wasn't any judging of a person involved in the decision.